# AdMob and AdWhirl confusion with iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, admob, adwhirl

I spent a few hours this afternoon trying to get an old iOS app project from last Spring to run on an iPhone4 with iOS6 and ran into all manner of errors concerning *arm7s* and the AdWhirl framework.

In trying to sort it out I discovered that my AdWhirl SDK is out of date so I tried to update it but then it also seems that AdWhirl is now AdMob. And AdMob is now Google. I am completely confused. The example code in the current AdWhirl SDK seems out of date and won't compile. Same for the AdMob sample code. Most of the links I searched out for info are also outdated.

Can someone explain to me (slowly and in plain English) the current state of things as of **November 27, 2012**:

1. Is AdWhirl basically irrelevant now?
2. Does AdMob perform the same
   sort of ad mediation?
3. Does AdMob run on iOS6?
4. Finally, is there a current tutorial for implementing AdMob? (the info on their site is
   conflicting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and 2 - Google AdMob started offering Mediation as part of it's product about 6-7 months ago, and has pretty much become the successor of AdWhirl. It offers the same sort of mediation, has more ad network choices, is more stable, and is better supported by Google. It also has additional features that AdWhirl doesn't have, such as support for formats other than 320x50, and the ability to set country level network ordering. AdWhirl is now in maintenance mode, though tbh I'm not sure what the status of armv7s support is on the latest iOS AdWhirl SDK.

3 - AdMob does run on iOS6 (has armv7s support), since v6.2.0.

4 - [This guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation) should be sufficient to get you up and running with mediation. Remember you'll need to include all SDK and adapter libraries for the ad networks you're mediating with. The AdMob network is already baked into the AdMob Mediation library.